# SSD encryption for storage purposes

Tags: ssd, encryption

I have a laptop with a HDD (1TB) and a SSD (15GB). On the HDD I have 3 differnt OS installed. So I was thinking to use the SSD as a storage for Music and such so it can be accessed by all of the OS.

For that I would like to encrypt the SSD, which should be an ecryption mechanism that can be decrypted by both, Windows and Linux.

I wanted to use truecrypt but that seems not to be secure anymore.
Do you have any other suggestions what encryption mechanism to use?

Comment: VTC as a product recommendation request.  Possible dupe: [Cross-platform file encryption tool](http://superuser.com/questions/381849/cross-platform-file-encryption-tool), see this over on the SoftwareRecs SE: [Alternatives to TrueCrypt?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt)

Comment: As far as anyone knows, TrueCrypt *is* still secure. Preliminary reviews of its source code seem to support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Veracrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) is a fork of TrueCrypt, still under active development and with a vibrant community. I would check them out. I've had success using it on both Mac OSX and Windows.

And TrueCrypt, I agree on steering clear - for the time being. Although the claimed insecurity of the program hasn't been proven, there is a lot of questionable activity going on with the program and the software's project page. With many viable alternatives out there, you may as well move to something that more active - such as VeraCrypt.